# ¿ como usar una sentencia update en java web?

Tags: java, jsp, oracle-11g, servlets

Estoy intentado modificar datos de una tabla con la sentencia update en java web, uso un servlet  para capturar los datos y enviarlos a una clase de java llamada "*adoproducto*" con un metodo llamado "*Modificar*" que recibe dos parametros `id` (tipo integer) y `descipcion`(tipo varchar). mi priblema es el siguiente:

Cuando escribo la sentencia de esta forma

```
 Consulta="UPDATE producto SET descripcion = '"+descripcion+"' WHERE id ="+id;
```

simplemente el servlet no se ejecuta solo carga y carga pero nunca se ejecuta, luego cuando escribo la sentecia de esta forma

```
 Consulta="UPDATE producto SET descripcion = "+descripcion+" WHERE id ="+id;
```

si ejecuta el servlet pero no modifica nigun registro, en mi opinion la forma correcta es la primera nótese que en el primer caso en el campo descripcion uso comillas simples por que es de tipo varchar y el segundo caso no lo hago pero si logra ejecutar el servlet.

```
public boolean  Modificar(String descripcion ,int id){
if (!conexion.estaconectado()){          
  conexion.conectar();
   }    
  String Consulta="";
  Consulta="UPDATE producto SET descripcion = '"+descripcion+"' WHERE id ="+id;

  int r=conexion.EnviarActualizacion(Consulta);
  if (r!=0){
  return true;
  }
  else{
  return false;
  }
}


public class conexion {
public static  Connection cnx = null;
public static String msg ="";

public static String conectar(){

try{   
    /*pro.agrega(entipro);*/
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
   cnx= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","SYSTEM","system");
  msg="conectado";
   } 
catch(SQLException e){
 msg = e.getMessage();
   }
catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
msg = e.getMessage();
   }
return msg;
}

public static boolean estaconectado(){

    if (cnx!=null){
    return true;
    }
    else{
     return false;
    }
}

public static int EnviarActualizacion(String cons){
   try {
      return ejecutarActualizacion(cnx.prepareStatement(cons));
       }
   catch (SQLException e){
      msg="Error al actualizar tabla : " + e.getMessage();
       }
     return 0;
       } 


public static int ejecutarActualizacion(PreparedStatement sp){

 try{
     return sp.executeUpdate();
 }catch(SQLException e){
     msg ="eror al actualizar la tabla"+ e.getMessage();
 }
 return 0;
}
```

}

---

```
String des = request.getParameter("descripcion");
int codigo = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("codigo"));
  lnegocio ln = new lnegocio();
  boolean estado = ln.modificar(des, codigo);           
  out.println(estado);
```

Comment: puedes poner tu método "EnviarActualizacion" para ver que hace?

Comment: Hola ya le agrege el codigo que faltaba.

Comment: que te devuelve el error del get.Message()? debe de darte un mensaje, por que como tu lo dices en efecto la sentencia con las comillas sencillas debería de trabajar bien

Comment: Esta muy mal que tu variable empiece con mayusculas. Creo que la solución es como en la primera forma pero te faltan las comitas del final: `consulta="UPDATE producto SET descripcion = '"+descripcion+"' WHERE id ='"+id+"';";`. Aún asi eso susceptible a inyección SQL mejor usa `PreparedStatement`